# how can i resolve error ? : node.scrollTo is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

When I run onPress in TodoItem component, I want scrollTo to be executed and scroll down as much as y: height value

but if i run onPress

node.scrollTo is not a function << this error occure

this is my code

(TodoList.js)

```
    import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect, createRef} from 'react';
    import {FlatList} from 'react-native';
    import {
      Dimensions,
      NativeSyntheticEvent,
      NativeScrollEvent,
      ScrollView,
    } from 'react-native';

    const TodoList = ({replycomment}) => {


      const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
      const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = useState(0);
      const flatListRef = React.useRef()
      const refScrollView = createRef();
    
      return (
        
        <FlatList
        ref={refScrollView}
          style={{height}}
          contentOffset={{x: 0, y: height}}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <TodoItem
            onPress={() => {
              const node = refScrollView.current;
              if (node) {
                node.scrollTo({x:0, y: height, animated: true});
              }
            }}
            />
          )}
        />
```

(TodoItem.js)

```
        import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
        import {FlatList} from 'react-native';


        const TodoItem = ({onPress}) => {


        return (
            
        
        <MainContainer onPress={onPress}>
            <Label>hi</Label>
        </MainContainer>
```

i'm not sure why this error happend. how can i fix my code?? i want to use FlatList

Comment: The object that is present in `node` apparently doesn't have a `scrollTo` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **Github** source code of `FlatList`, I can only see 4 methods which help with *scroll* functionality :-

```
scrollToEnd(params?: ?{animated?: ?boolean, ...})
```

```
scrollToIndex(params: {
    animated?: ?boolean,
    index: number,
    viewOffset?: number,
    viewPosition?: number,
    ...
  })
```

```
scrollToItem(params: {
    animated?: ?boolean,
    item: ItemT,
    viewPosition?: number,
    ...
  })
```

```
scrollToOffset(params: {animated?: ?boolean, offset: number, ...})
```

I think you need to make use of either of the above (since `FlatList` doesn't implement it's own `scrollTo`). I can see `scrollTo` usage inside `VirtualizedList` which is internally returned by `FlatList`.

Link to the source code - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Lists/FlatList.js

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using something like this :

node.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' })